# Adding an event handler to a changing session value in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, event-handling, logout

Can I add an event handler to a session value in asp.net with c#?
I'm planning to update the database when user logs in and logs out and I control login and logout with session values, but the session may end without a user click, like timeout, so I'd like to add an event handler to "isloggedin" session value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to handle this in global.asax.

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 //your code
}

protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `Session_End` method in the global.asax.  There, you will retrieve what information you need from the session, and do what you need to (like setting logout flag in database for the user):

Here's an example of what I do, though you can tailor it to your needs:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SessionPlayerContext context = (SessionPlayerContext)this.Session[Constants.SessionKeys.UserContext];
    if (context != null)
        PlayerManager.SetPlayerOnlineStatus(context.PlayerID, false);
}
```

The key is that I'm getting the user object that I previously stored in the session (when user logged in), and if it exists, I then flag the user as being logged out in the database (via PlayerManager)

Not only should you check it in the `Session_End`, but you also should check it wherever user would physically log out.

As for setting the user as being logged in, you will handle that when user physically logs in.